# Is my MacPro 5,1 single or dual socket?

Tags: mac-pro

My MacPro 5,1 is running a 3.33 GHz 6-Core Intel Xeon with 16 GB 1333 MHz DDR3. Is this a single or a dual socket system? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Take the side off & look ;)

A 6-core is probably a single socket, a 12 would be a dual.

You can also tell from About this Mac > Memory.

Dual socket has 8 RAM slots, single has 4.

single…

[image]

dual…

[image]

The sockets are on a daughter-card which slides out & is replaceable/interchangeable.

Image from OWC

[image]

Comment: Just checked. It's a single core. Thanks.

Comment: Rog - if this answered your question sufficiently, please check the 'tick mark' next to it (I don't need the points it will give me, but it signifies to future googlers that a satisfactory answer was found.) Welcome to Ask Different. Hope you stick around :)